# Toggle display:none with div in front of another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, fadeto

I'm trying to make a div that I have on top of another div show up when you click on something.

This is the code for the two divs, without all the stuff that's within each:

```
<div id="randomarticle_enlarge">
    <h1></h1>
    <h4></h4>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
</div>
<div class="bodybag">
    <h1></h1>
    <h4></h4>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
</div>
```

Then I have css for each, of course:

```
.bodybag {
width:960px;
}
#randomarticle_englarge {
height:750px;
width:960px;
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
margin-top:1px;
padding-left:20px;
padding-right:20px;
display: none;
}
```

Am I supposed to have the bodybag class have a z-index and a position:relative? Because even though I don't it's working (at this point).

Anyway, I have this script written that's doing exactly what I want it to do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.popular').click(function() {
    $('#textmask').fadeTo( 'fast', 0.1);
    $('#backgroundmask').css('background-color', 'white');
    });
});
```

And all I want to happen next is that as the textmask and the backgroundmask fade in/change as they should and do, is for the randomarticle_enlarge div to show up.

I've tried using .toggle and .toggleClass and .slideToggle and .show but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning must be relative to a container. In order to absolutely position something you need to indicate what it's absolutely positioned to. Something along these lines.

```
<div id="randomarticle_englargeContainer">
    <div id="randomarticle_englarge">
    </div>
    <div class="bodybag">
    </div>
</div>


#randomarticle_englargeContainer {
    position: relative;
}
.bodybag {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When copying everything from above I have no issues using `$('#randomarticle_englarge').toggle();`. Check your browser's console for errors; you might find the answers there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure about what would you like to do with the divs, but I created an example for you, maybe this is what you want:

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gsfdC/)**

So there is two divs. The 2nd div covers the 1st one. Clicking on a 'button' hides the 2nd div, so the 1st one reveals. Clicking again the 'button', the 2nd div appears and covers the 1st one again.

HTML:

```
<div class="popular">Click me!</div>
<div class="container">
    <div id="randomarticle_enlarge">
        <h1>A</h1>
        <h4>B</h4>
        <p>C</p>
        <p>D</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bodybag">
        <h1>E</h1>
        <h4>F</h4>
        <p>G</p>
        <p>H</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.bodybag {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

#randomarticle_enlarge {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;  
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.popular').click(function() {
    $('#randomarticle_enlarge').toggleClass('hide');
    });
});
```